# How to set verbose_name for external app model in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I'm trying to set `verbose_name` for a model `SocialAuthUser` from [django_social](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django).

I've tried to use proxy model, setting its `Meta.verbose_name` to desired value, but had no success (probably I did it wrong). If it's the way to go, I can provide more details.

It would be great to avoid installing module from pip in editable mode just to replace `verbose_name` in admin site.

Probably I can replace model name in admin site in some other way?
I thought about adding custom link to admin site, but didn't research this method yet because it feels hacky.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Changing the list/form label for a specific field of the external model I assume, right?

Comment: I need to display more human readable (in another language) name on the main admin site page for this model. So, not the field name, but the model name. And I don't really care about python class name for this model as long as displayed name is what I need.

Comment: Check my answer. I thought you want to change the `verbose_name` of a field which is trickier as you have to override the model form and create a method field with custom `short_description`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right. For your changes on the proxy model to take effect you need to unregister the model from admin site first and then register the proxy model.

The example below is for `social_django.Association` model.

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from social_django.admin import AssociationOption
from social_django.models import Association


class AssociationProxy(Association):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = 'custom model'
        app_label = 'social_django'


admin.site.unregister(Association)
admin.site.register(AssociationProxy, AssociationOption)
```

This assumes you are using the default admin site

```
# urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Thank you. Although I'm using custom admin site, your solution did work for me.    The only difference was I (un)registered models with my custom AdminSite instance.

Comment: excuse me. how i can to change verbose name for app.